# Facebook share problem on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook

I use this code for facebook share and with iphone but it is opening new window( window.open ) I want to open new div How can I do that?    I want Like( `$("#DIV").open(http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=,......)`  )

```
<script>
function fbs_click() {
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false;
}
</script>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"><img src="ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE" alt="Share on Facebook" /></a>
```